# Controlling compiler inline optimization for memcpy

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, memcpy

I like compiler inline optimization of memcpy instructions. On the arm processor I have found that it seems to inline up to 64 bytes with both gcc and clang. Without the inlining it seems to go to a byte copy routine that is significantly slower. It would be nice to do more than that but I can't figure out which optimization flags control the 64 bytes. Can anyone provide a suggestion for more inlining or alternative?

Here is an example:
test.c:

```c
typedef struct {
    float data[16];
} A;

int main() {
    volatile A a = {};
    A b = a; 
    return 0;
}
```

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O3 -c test.c
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d test.o | awk -v RS= '/^[[:xdigit:]]+ <main>/' # printing just main
...
  24:   e8ae000f    stmia   lr!, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
  28:   e8bc000f    ldm ip!, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
  2c:   e8ae000f    stmia   lr!, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
  30:   e8bc000f    ldm ip!, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
...
```

where if I make data size 17, I will instead get:

```
  28:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <memcpy>
```

I'm using -specs=nano.specs which defines a small memcpy routine that does reduce to doing byte operations.

```
000082bc <memcpy>:
    82bc:   e2403001    sub r3, r0, #1
    82c0:   e0812002    add r2, r1, r2
    82c4:   e1510002    cmp r1, r2
    82c8:   012fff1e    bxeq    lr
    82cc:   e4d1c001    ldrb    ip, [r1], #1
    82d0:   e5e3c001    strb    ip, [r3, #1]!
    82d4:   eafffffa    b   82c4 <memcpy+0x8>
```

In my specific case it is used in a 500 cycle interrupt routine. The 64 byte memcpy adds about 30 cycles, while the byte copy version adds 900, which is somewhat linked to optimizations of the ST cortex M4 controller that I'm using. I've otherwise optimized the interrupt routine for minimal branches, etc. so this memcpy does provide a significant challenge to running at my target execution speed.

Comment: If it stops at 64 bytes, the compiler programmers probably determined that the optimization doesn't provide much benefit after that. What makes you think that inlining more will actually be faster?

Comment: "a byte copy routine" really? Otherwise, memcpy expansion is done in the backend in gcc, and each target has its own options. Arm seems to hardcode 64 in arm_gen_cpymemqi, so you are out of luck there. x86 has `-mmemcpy-strategy` for instance.

Comment: Did you benchmark your tries? Did you disassemble the `memcpy` to be sure that it copies bytes?